# What Off-Chain programming languages are important in Blockchain development

Tags: development

I am looking at getting into Blockchain development, and I would like to have some idea about general programming languages that are relatively important compared to the general developer-market.

Myself, I know C++ and C# well, but it would be interesting to combine getting into Blockchain with getting into Python or Functional language or similar.  (Possibly GO or stable parts of JavaScript stacks, probably not Java)

Are some on-chain languages related to particular off-chain languages?